# What is the most efficient way to check if a value of a list is contained in one of the other values of the list?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

Lately I have tried to solve a problem that I have in my code that is about checking if a value of a list is contained in other value of the same list. My specific list contains phone numbers, so it looks like that:

```py
['972526174656' , '526174656' , '174656']
```

but the way I want it to look like is that:

```py
['972526174656']
```

I have tried to solve it with the easiest way of doing for inside another for:

```py
phones_list = ['972526174656' , '526174656' , '174656']
drop_list = []
for phone in phones_list:
    for phone2 in phones_list:
        if phone2.contains(phone) and phone2!=phone:
           drop_list.append(phone)
phones_list = list(set(phones_list) - set(drop_list))
```

Although this example works, its efficiency is bad and in my original data I have 3,000,000 cases like the one I showed you. So **efficiency is the key for my code to succeed!**

I hope the community could help me to solve this. Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Comment: You can improve it a little by sorting the list by length. Then the inner loop should only check the elements after the current element of the outer loop.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this that isn't O(n^2)

Comment: Is the overlap always at the end? You can use `.endswith()` instead of `.contains()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations`:

```
phones_list = ['972526174656' , '526174656' , '174656']
drop_list = []

for p1,p2 in itertools.permutations(phones_list, 2):
    if p1 in p2:
        drop_list.append(p1)

phones_list = list(set(phones_list) - set(drop_list))
```

Comment: This has the same efficiency as the nested loops.

Comment: Yes, the same Big-O of O(n^2), but slightly better efficiency?

Comment: The solution in the duplicate question is probably better because it doesn't generate all permutations, only when `p1` longer than `p2`.

Comment: Unless sorting the list first cancels out the benefit.

Comment: i performed the 2 options on my jupyter notebook and quamrana itertools.permutations is 7 times faster then the option i showed!!!

Comment: Any upvotes would be appreciated.

Comment: although this solution worked pretty good, if someone has another solution i will be happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

```
phones_list = ['972526174656' , '526174656' , '174656']
phones_list.sort(reverse=True)

i = 0
while i < len(phones_list):
    j = i + 1
    while j  < len(phones_list):
        if phones_list[j] in phones_list[i]:
            phones_list.pop(j)
        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1
phones_list
```

output:

```
['972526174656']
```

Comment: @nadavfr31 can you also test my solution against your data?

Comment: just checked your solution and unfortunetly its less efficient(twice less) then quamrana solution. thanks for your try!!

Comment: what if you do not sort the list?

Comment: still not efficient...

Comment: how much the phone_list is dropping? from 3milions how many after ?

Comment: around 60% of data will be dropped off...

Comment: they are sorted of just random?

Comment: its a little bit hard to explain but i will try... imagine you have 1,000,000 different id's and that each id has arround 3 rows(could be more and could be less) of phone numbers. what im trying to do is to get only the unique and not contained phone numbers for each id